# How do I mount USB CDROM Drive

Tags: linux, usb, devices, usb-device, data-cd

I have an external usb cdrom drive but cannot find it in RHEL 7.4. The attached image is the results of my "ls /dev/".

[image]

When I execute the "cat /var/log/dmesg | grep usb" I get the below results but I don't see in it what dev file it is at so that I can mount it.

```
[    4.681422] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    4.681434] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    4.682125] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    5.335985] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    5.335988] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    5.335990] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    5.335993] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 ehci_hcd
[    5.335995] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    5.346949] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    5.346952] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    5.346954] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    5.346956] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 ehci_hcd
[    5.346959] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    5.347844] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    5.347857] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    5.347859] usb usb3: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    5.347862] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.x86_64 uhci_hcd
[    5.347864] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.4
[    5.348454] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[    5.348465] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[    5.348475] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[    5.637865] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    5.648863] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    5.752239] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    5.752243] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    5.763238] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    5.763244] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    5.910216] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    5.910218] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    6.031908] usb 1-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    6.034889] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    6.120714] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=2660
[    6.120717] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    6.124270] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0461, idProduct=4e22
[    6.124272] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    6.124274] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[    6.124276] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: PixArt
[    6.127793] input: PixArt USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/input/input1
[    6.128253] hid-generic 0003:0461:4E22.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [PixArt USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.5/input0
[    6.190888] usb 1-1.6: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    6.277905] usb 1-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2101
[    6.277912] usb 1-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    6.277915] usb 1-1.6: Product: Dell Smart Card Reader Keyboard
[    6.277919] usb 1-1.6: Manufacturer: Dell
[    6.281094] input: Dell Dell Smart Card Reader Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input2
[    6.332079] hid-generic 0003:413C:2101.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Dell Dell Smart Card Reader Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input0
```

I'm running RHEL 7.4. Thank you.

The cdrom drive is Dell and it looks like it is showing in the lsusb results:

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2660 Standard Microsystems Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2101 Dell Computer Corp. SmartCard Reader Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 047: ID 0461:4e22 Primax Electronics, Ltd
Bus 001 Device 071: ID 413c:9016 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: `dmesg` without | grep might be interesting (if you `| grep` everything it makes you miss things). If you are able to (un)plug the USB device, whatever messages appear in dmesg when you do that. Also, does it show up in lsusb?

Comment: Please see update. It looks like it is in Bus 001 Device 071.

Comment: When I try to cd into /dev/bus/usb/001/071 it says it is not a directory

Comment: Please edit question with the lines in `dmesg` that appear after you plug in the Dell USB CDROM drive. No grepping, please. Besides the USB enumeration, you should see a message that a kernel driver is claiming this device. If that doesn't happen, your kernel may not have the necessary drivers (`sr_mod`, resp. SCSI-CD-ROM support). Don't try to use the `/dev/bus/usb` files, they are for USB-level communication.